# Valgrind C: Argument of function has a fishy (possibly negative) value

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I'm getting this error message in multiple places in my code where I call malloc or realloc. Here is one example.

```
void* reallocate_array(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    return realloc(ptr,size)
}
```

EDIT2: Looks like the problem is in the test case. I can't modify this

```
char* reallocated = (char*) reallocate_array(allocated,-1)
```

Here is my solution which got rid of the fishy value error

```
if((int)size < 0)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

I was under the impression that size_t was an unsigned integer, meaning it could never be negative. Could this be bug in Valgrind or is it warning me of a possible wraparound?

EDIT: Valgrind output

```
==20841== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:
==20841== Argument 'size' of function realloc has a fishy (possibly negative) value: -1
==20841==    at 0x4C2BB78: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:785)
==20841==    by 0x4057B1: reallocate_array (allocation.c:24)
==20841==    by 0x402A8A: reallocate_NegativeBytes_Test::TestBody() (tests.cpp:56)
```

Comment: What is the valgrind output?

Comment: It says **possibly negative**, fishy might mean something else. Also, you should show the call instead.

Comment: It is smelling a fishy value that might result from integer overflow (or some other bug) and letting you know. You better check it.

Comment: So I'm assuming that means I need to call sizeof(size_t) and then determine the maximum possible value from those bytes

Comment: No. It is meaning that you should check your code for bugs. Any value of `size` is legal. Some just suspicious.

Comment: It means you need to check where `reallocate_array` is being called to see what gets passed in.

Comment: didnt you get a warning when calling reallocate_array with a negative value, its declared to take `size_t` - ie unsigned

Comment: I'd call that an invalid test case.

Comment: What is the purpose of that test?

Comment: hmm, i just tried it and you can pass without any error -1 into size_t function. In this case valgirnd is being really good, It is fishy to call realloc with a size of -1. You need to test size in reallocate_array

Comment: I added a solution which gets rid of the error message

Comment: I guess someone was lazy to type `SIZE_MAX`

Comment: I wonder why Valgrind doesn't show the value in hexadecimal too (there's no option for that, right?). That would help realize in my case that I forgot I was subtracting a small value from SIZE_MAX. That results in a negative value if we're talking about a signed integer - not if we're talking about a size_t type which is always positive.

Answer (score 3):

Props to Valgrind: it is quite right that passing a negative actual argument to a parameter of unsigned type is fishy.  The result in your particular case will be that the argument is converted to the largest representable value of type `size_t`, but that may very well be different from what was intended.

I suspect that the conversion to a large, positive unsigned value is indeed different from what was intended by your test case.  Inasmuch as the test case expects the memory allocation to fail, the case probably was passing, *but not for the reason I suspect its author anticipated*.  At minimum, it is a bad test case on account of being unclear about what it is intended to test.

As for your solution, it is fishy, too.  The standard has this to say about your conversion of `(size_t) -1` to type `int`:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

([C2011 6.3.1.3/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3))

Implementation-defined behavior and the possibility of a signal is not a comfortable place to hang your hat.

If you insist on validating the value inside the function, then you might consider this test:

```
if (size & ~(SIZE_MAX >> 1)) {
    // ...
}
```

That tests whether the most-significant bit of `size` is set, which it will be if the value was converted from any negative number of a type no wider than `size_t`.

Myself, however, I would try to get the test case changed or dropped.  Use Valgrind's complaints about it to support your argument, if you wish.